# GP events with missing ga_session_id in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have noticed some behavior in our data.
In some % we don't have ga_session_id as param on events.
For example we have custom event missions_started and we see that in 20% of the cases we are missing ga_session_id as param in this event.

App is using Firebase SDK 17.5.0.

What can be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be :

1. If the event is filtered out from a subproperty.
2. Consent leads to NULL values. Those users who don't consent will have null values in session_id params.
3. Certain AD Blockers would also cause NULL values as well.